# check if method has comment with antlr

Tags: java, comments, antlr4

changes to  [Java.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4)

begining of file

```
grammar Java;


@lexer::members {
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
    public static final int COMMENTS = 2;
}
```

end of file

```
//
// Whitespace and comments
//

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(WHITESPACE) ;  // channel(1)

COMMENT    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(COMMENTS)  ; // channel(2)

LINE_COMMENT    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(COMMENTS) ;   // channel(2)
```

Trying to send comments and whitespace to different channels as done in book "The Definitive ANTLR 4
Reference" Chapter 12.1 Broadcasting Tokens on Different Channels

upon executing antlr4 Java.g4 following errors are shown

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool Java.g4
    warning(155): Java.g4:1017:35: rule WS contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output
    warning(155): Java.g4:1019:40: rule COMMENT contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output
    warning(155): Java.g4:1021:45: rule LINE_COMMENT contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output
```

I do not see whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the following fragment:

```
@lexer::members {
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
    public static final int COMMENTS = 2;
}
```

with string:

```
channels { WHITESPACE, COMMENTS }
```

Comment: adds a new error [error(164): Java.g4:42:0: custom channels are not supported in combined grammars]

Comment: In this case you should separate Lexer and Parser to different files: JavaLexer and JavaParser.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to split lexer and parser files.
and as [kvanttt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1046374/kvanttt) to use `channels { WHITESPACE, COMMENTS }` in lexer file
full files will be uploaded to my fork of https://github.com/nkv123/grammars-v4 repository.